kubectl commands not working on k8s worker-node
When I run the command kubectl get pod it shows the error:

E0529 06:34:46.052414   11652 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused. The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused, did you specify the right host or port?

How to resolve this error?
I have done the below steps on the master node.
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

Master is working fine but worker-node is showing the error.

Hi there, it would be helpful to get more information about your setup. Is this a minikube setup? Or something else? Also you could share kubeconfig files etc.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

You almost never directly log into Kubernetes nodes IME; like Pods the core model is generally that they can be dynamically created and destroyed.  Run kubectl from your local system.
